# Rails allowing admin to add tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to allow admin to add tags. I created a new tag page in active admin but i'm getting an error undefined method 'actions'.

user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation,  {:tag_list => []}

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register_page "Tags" do
  content do
     form do |f|
        f.input :tag_list, label: "Medium/Process"
        f.actions
     end
   end    
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **register** method and **Tag** resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tag do
...
end
```

And User model should `has_many :tags`. There you can build you custom logic.

Or you can populate tags in the User resource via nested forms:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
   f.inputs :tags do
      f.has_many :tags, heading: 'Themes', allow_destroy: true do |ft|
        ft.input :title
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I had to create a tag model `class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
end` aswell

Comment: Hi again, when I add tags it adds in admin mode but it doesn't show up in the actual app. But when I delete it deletes from both back and front end. Any idea why the tag added from admin is not showing up in the app?